# Shutdown computer with Syslinux - poweroff.c32 & acpioff.c32

Tags: pxe-boot, bios, syslinux

Does anyone know how i could shutdown ACPI Bios computer (without APM) using Syslinux ?

This is the configuration I am using :

```
 LABEL Shutdown
    MENU LABEL ^Shutdown computer
    KERNEL /tools/poweroff.c32
    TEXT HELP
        Shutdown the computer
    ENDTEXT
```

On a non-APM Bios computer I got the error:

```
 APM not present
```

I heard that new Bios use most of the time ACPI instead of APM.
So i tried acpioff.c32 from https://launchpadlibrarian.net/187530745/acpioff.c32

and replaced poweroff.c32 with it

```
 mv acpioff.c32 poweroff.c32
```

But i got the error :

```
 Failed to load com32 poweroff.c32
```

Maybe it require some dependencies? but I didn't found them...

I tested it from CDRom, USB Key and LPXE with the same result

Does anyone know how I could have shutdown works on ACPI using Syslinux ?

Thanks

**PS**

I already tried COM32 instead of KERNEL, but it is the same as said in :
http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#KERNEL_file

> KERNEL recognized extension (case sensitive)
>
> .0    PXE bootstrap program (NBP) [PXELINUX only] .bin    "CD boot sector"
>   [ISOLINUX only]
>
> .bs   Boot sector [SYSLINUX only]
>
> .bss  Boot sector, DOS superblock will be patched in [SYSLINUX only]
>
> .c32  COM32 image (32-bit COMBOOT)
>
> .cbt  COMBOOT image (not runnable from DOS)
>
> .com  COMBOOT image (runnable from DOS)
>
> .img  Disk image [ISOLINUX only]

I tried with Syslinux libraries from BIOS folder and EFI64 with the same result

This is the list of file I included :

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution to turn off using acpi?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix com32 modules from one version of syslinux/pxelinux with another version of syslinux/pxelinux.

If you want to build a working pxelinux and acpioff.c32, build the code from the tip of this branch:
https://github.com/awalls-cx18/syslinux/tree/acpi_off?files=1

Answer (score 0):

You want to use COM32 to send the poweroff command. Your error code gave a bit of a hint. More info from the [Arch Wiki/Syslinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/syslinux#Reboot_and_power_off)

```
 LABEL poweroff
     MENU LABEL Power Off
     COM32 poweroff.c32
```

Comment: I already tested that before, com32 and kernel are doing the same thing, i added a link in my post  :  http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#KERNEL_file. Btw the trouble come from acpioff.c32, the original poweroff.c32 works as i mentioned, but only on APM bios....